# How do I hide a base class property in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have the the following property in a class:

```
protected Int32 MyProperty { get; set; }
```

and in a derived class I want to override it with:

```
protected Long MyProperty {get ;set; }
```

Is the only way to do this with the `new` keyword so that the base class property can be hidden?

Comment: `Long MyInt`? Why would you do this??

Comment: `MyInt` is not a property in your example.  It is a field.

Comment: I changed the property to be something less meaningful so answerers didn't get hung up on the word 'Int'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overrides must be the same signature as what they are overriding, so you can't change the type of a field.

Comment: Wouldn't that only be the base signature? ie. anything that can be downcast to the original signature would be acceptable (and hence, long to int, works very well)

Answer (score 3):

Another option than trying to override in this fashion is to make your class generic;

```
public abstract class MyClass<T>
{
   public T MyValue{ get; set;}
}

public class MyIntClass : MyClass<int>
{}

public class MyLongClass : MyClass<long>
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not overriding the `MyInt` field, you're creating a new field, through which you have to specified `new`:

```
protected new Long MyInt = 0;
```

If you code is accessing the class as an instance of your base class, it will access it as `Int32`, if you call your subclass directly, it will access it as `Long`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    protected int MyValue = 0;
}

public class MySubclass : MyClass
{
    protected new long MyValue = 0;
}

void Test()
{
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    instance.MyValue = 10; // int

    MySubclass instance2 = new MySubclass();
    instance2.MyValue = 10; // long

    MyClass instance3 = (MyClass)instance2;
    int value = instance3.MyValue; // int - value is 0.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ebca9ah3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or the [new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) modifier for the property to override it. Still, the two properties need to be the same type. The difference is that `override` is also called if you call the property on a `Base` class which is in fact the `Derived` class and `new` is only used if you call it on the `derived` class. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-s-the-difference-between-code-override-code-and-code-new-code.aspx) interesting article by Jon Skeet explaining the difference. As Jon says there, if you write

```
Base b = new Derived();
b.SomeMethod();
```

and `SomeMethod` was overriden using the `override` keyword, the method of the derived class would be called. If you would use the `new` keyword, the method `SomeMethod` from the base class would be called.

Comment: They're different types. One is `Long` and one is `Int32`.